# interface as parameter in a method in c#

Tags: c#, interface

I have defined an interface `IActivity` and then created two classes that implement this interface as

```
public class EngagementActivity : IActivity...
```

and

```
public class MPEngagementActivity : IActivity...
```

I have then created a method to save the activities to the database as follows

```
public void SaveActivity (IActivity activity)
```

The problem I am having is that when I pass a parameter of type `EngagementActivity` or `MPEngagementActivity` to this method Visual Studio complains about non matching types.

Am I doing this wrong?

Here is the calling code (incomplete I know...)

```
public ActionResult UpdateEngagementActivityRecord(EngagementActivityViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        svc.SaveActivityRecord(model.Activity);
        //Redirect to Index?
    }

    InitialiseEngagementActivityViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

and here is the method (incomplete)

```
internal void SaveActivityRecord(IActivity model)
{
    Activity record = new Activity();

    if (model != null)
    {

       dbContext.Activities.Add(record);
       Save();
    }
}
```

the error message is:

> The best overloaded method match for SaveActivityRecord(IActivity)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Please show the declaration of `EngagementActivityViewModel.Activity`.

Answer (score 5):

Check declaration of your *SaveActivity(IActivity activity)* if *IActivity* is a class from your namespace, and is not something like *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Uml.Activities.IAcitivity*

Answer (score 1):

According to your provided information `You are not doing anything wrong`. It must be something else. Best way restart your Visual Studio :)

Your Classes `Implements IActivity` Interface then they can passed as an IActivity Interface. We did this basic OOPS concept for implementing `polymorphism` - I don't know how many times.

So It is something else.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to implement one of the members of the interface... duh!

Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: were you not getting the warning - that implement all members ?